# Impedir que borrar o mover archivo/directorio pero si que pueda crear, editar... etc un usuario en Ubuntu (linux???)

Tags: ubuntu, permisos

Soy nuevo en el foro y en Ubuntu y les quería preguntar si existe la posibilidad de impedir que un usuario específico borre o mueva un archivo/directorio pero si pueda crear, editar archivos/directorios. Dicho de otra manera, queremos habilitar el permiso de escritura completo pero que impida el acceso a borrar.
Trabajo en un empresa donde hay ejecutivos, ellos necesitan enviar información al servidor cada cierto tiempo y queremos impedir que ellos la borren (cuando son despedidos por ejemplo).

Tenemos Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.

Tenemos WINSCP en los equipos con windows para que asi ellos puedan ingresar el servidor sftp (en Ubuntu) sin problema y puedan ir guardando sus archivos.

Instale lshell tratando de limitar el comando rm y mv pero solo afecta a la consola no a los programas de transferencia de archivos.

existe alguna alternativa para solucionar mi problema?

Comment: Si pueden editar, pueden borrar: nada impediría a un usuario editar un archivo y dejarlo vacío. Por esto los dos permisos suelen ir de la mano

Answer (score -1):

Lo más cercano a lo que buscas sería usar el sticky bit. De la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit):

> Cuando se le asigna a un directorio, significa que los elementos que
>   hay en ese directorio sólo pueden ser renombrados o borrados por el
>   propietario del elemento, el propietario del directorio o el usuario
>   root, aunque el resto de usuarios tenga permisos de escritura y, por
>   tanto, puedan modificar el contenido de esos elementos

```
chmod +t <ruta_del_directorio>
```